# Hibernate: session.load vs session.get

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I was under the impression that `session.load()` loads the proxy object in the cache while `session.get()` always hits the database but I am confused after watching a JavaBrains [video](https://youtu.be/RmnrgocuivQ?list=PL4AFF701184976B25).

According to this video when we are calling the below get method it is loading the proxy object of `UserDetails` in the memory.

```
user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
```

Structure of `UserDetails` is

[image]

While in the comment section, a guy commented:

> there is no proxy of User class, instead the proxy object of the
> collection is created.

Now there are two questions here.

> 1st: Related to fetching strategies and creation of proxy objects in case of session.load() and session.get() which has been answered below by me.
>
> 2nd: In this case, the proxy object will create for UserDetails or for collection (still to be answered).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.Fetching Strategies:** There is no effect of fetching strategies in the working of session.get or session.load (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-lazy).

**2. Session.get:** It **never returns proxy**,
As per the hibernate docs : (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get(java.lang.Class, java.io.Serializable))

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance. (If the instance is already associated with the session, return that instance. This method never returns an uninitialized instance.)

Means `get` method first check the cache if the `fully initialize object` is present there if yes return that object otherwise it `hits the database to get the object` and returns the same after saving it in the cache space.

**3. Session.load:** As per the hibernate docs :

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming that the instance exists. This method might return a proxied instance that is initialized on-demand, when a non-identifier method is accessed.

Means `load` method first check the cache if the `fully initialize object` is present there and if yes returns that object else it returns the proxy(A proxy is a class that delegates to another object. Initially, when it's not initialized, it contains just the primary key. When you call a method, as the Javadoc says, it initializes, by loading the actual entity from the database, and the delegates to this loaded entity) of that object by `assuming that instance exists'.

**Note:** Important to note that `load` method `never throw an exception`.You will get `ObjectNotFoundException` in case you try to retrieve any other property instead of the primary key from the proxy object.As it will hit the database to load the object from there, which is not exists.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mentioned in the comment too. For your case to test, why dont you try `session.clear()` in your code and analyze results?
For clearing second level cache, read here:
https://dzone.com/articles/clearing-hibernate-second-leve

Comment: I still didn't get this. The video link seems passing false concept about `get()` method. If we call `get()` it should fetch all data including list of addresses in a single query. Now all data exist in cache. So when we call `user.getListOfAddresses()` should be returned from cache or should not hit the database. However, in video link, these two calls created two separate database queries which is really confusing. Could you please help with this?

Comment: @MAC, you are mixing the two things i.e. fetching strategies and hibernate methods get vs load. Hibernate by default use Lazy strategy in case of  (*) to many relationships. So if we call session.get() then it will fetch all list of addresses only if we have explicitly set the fetching strategy as eager.

Answer (score 3):

Here, `UserDetails` is the parent and `Address` is the child. Hibernate is actually lazy-loading the child  `Address`. So eventually all children elements (`Address` in this case) are not pre-loaded while you load the parent (`UserDetails` in this case).

So, when you do this:

```
user = (UserDetails) session.get(UserDetails.class, 1);
```

Hibernate is not actually loading all the child (`Collection<Address>`). Instead Hibernate load `Address` only when you explicitly access them. So Hibernate won't hit DB for `Address` table unless you really need them and that's the purpose of **lazy loading**.

What it means by **Lazy loading** is that while you get a proxy object of `UserDetails`, it doesn't really hit the `Address` table unless you try to access Collection elements explicitly. In other words, you need to iterate over the collection for Hibernate to fetch `Address` table.

You could end yourself into a situation where you hit the database everytime for each child (`Address`). So, make a explicit call `listOfAddresses.size()` so as to load all children at a time.

Also note that **Lazy loading** will happen by default for **One-To-Many** and **Many-To-Many** cases.

Comment: My question is actually related to fetching strategies and creation of proxy objects in case of session.load() and session.get() not  just what is eager and lazy loading.

Comment: Well you must understand `Load()` implements **lazy loading** and `get() ` never returns a proxy.

Comment: @ Rahul, that's the question why it is loading proxy object in case of get()

Comment: if the proxy is present in **cache**, `get()` can return a proxy. If its not initialized , `get()` will hit the database to make sure its an existing entity.
load() will **always** return a proxy. Basically get() will see the cache first and then loads from database. It doesnt matter whether the entity is present in cache, load() always returns a proxy. Check-in hibernate cache before DB look-up is a basic hibernate behavior and `session.get()` just follows that.

Comment: This answer makes lot of sense. I tried myself by creating and running the code. No too much thinking helps us to understand this concept.