# Hibernate : Returning a proxy object in case of session.load

Tags: java, hibernate

According to hibernate docs `session.load` :

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the given identifier, assuming that the instance exists. **This method might return a proxied instance that is initialized on-demand**, when a non-identifier method is accessed.

What I know is `session.load` first checks in the cache, if the persistent instance is present and if yes it will return that instance, otherwise it will throw the `ObjectNotFoundException`.

**Query:** In which case does `session.load` return the proxy object instead of fully initializing the persistent object from the cache? Is it related to fetching strategies `(lazy=true)` by default?

Comment: What you know is incorrect. As the javadoc says: it assumes that the instance exists. If the instance is not in the cache already, it returns a proxy, assuming that the entity exists. It will NOT throw an ObjectNotFoundException.

Comment: @JBNizet, then in which case it gives ObjectNotFoundException and is there no role of fetching strategies in case of session.load?

Comment: It won't. And no, fetching strategies have nothing to do with Session.load().

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the answer, could you please validate my one more assumption "a proxy object is an object having only primary key"? if yes then what will happen if we try to retrieve other properties from the same object?

Comment: That's not what a proxy is. A proxy is a class that **delegates** to another object. Initially, when it's not initialized, it contains just the primary key. When you call a method, as the javadoc says, it initializes, by loading the actual entity from the database, and the delegates to this loaded entity.

Comment: @JBNizet, then it should give exception in that case if we try to retrieve other properties from the proxy object, as it will try to load the actual entity from the database(which does not exist).

Comment: Yes, indeed. ...

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: @JBNizet, could you please verify this answer of `difference between session.get and session.load` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46153190/6242317) , It will be very helpful for me.